# Gitlab errors when committing iss files

Tags: gitlab, devops, inno-setup-v6

GitLab 16.5.1 Git version 2.42.0

Good day! Recently, a problem appeared in my gitlab with changing the contents of a file with the .iss extension. The symptoms are as follows: When trying to change the encoding using Visual Studio, it gives the error “fatal: failed to encode ‘gitlab.iss’ from CP1251 to UTF-8”.

I changed the encoding of the file. I tried to download via the gitlab Web IDE, but immediately got the error “13:write create blob: writing boot failed with error code 128”.

But the most interesting thing is if the file extension is left empty, then the contents of the file can be easily changed in any encoding.

There are no problems in other repositories!

If someone has encountered this problem and can tell you where to dig, I will be very grateful!

Gitlab logs confirm these errors.